# Expandable textview. How do I make it collapse to 2 lines, instead of 0 lines?

Tags: android, textview, expandable

[Here](https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout) is the library I am using.

I am able to expand my textview and minimize it. However, it minimizes fully. I just want to minimize it to 2 lines.

I have checked the github samples, but it looks like they use 2 textviews and toggle their visibility. I would like to avoid that. Here is the [code](https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/jp/android/aakira/sample/expandablelayout/exampleexpanded/ExampleReadMoreActivity.java) and [xml](https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/layout/activity_example_read_more.xml).

Here is my xml

```
<com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/expandable_opening_hours"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    app:ael_duration="500"
                    app:ael_expanded="true"
                    app:ael_interpolator="accelerate"
                    app:ael_orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView6"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/openingTextView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/medium_grey"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_12"
                        tools:text="Weekdays 7am - 9:30pm;  \nWeekend 7:30am - 8pm; PH Closed" />

                </com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: read library documentation

Comment: @YoLo i tried to look for it but couldnt find it. Do you know where it can be found?

Comment: Does `android:minLines="2"` not work?

Comment: @Zolly which feature you want from the library?

Answer (score 0):

If you setting the Visibility of a Textview to "Gone", It will minimize the whole textview. You have to go for two textviews.